# XPath with HTML

Tags: html, xpath

I have a html like this

```
<tr>
<td>
<div>Text1</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>Text2</div>
</td>
</tr>
...
```

I want to find Text1 with XPath, If i use this XPath `//tr[td/div[text()='Text1']]`

It works but if I try this `//tr[//div[text()='Text1']]`  doesn't works, returns every `<tr>` in the document even if `//div[text()='Text1']` only returns one.

I would like to know why it happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `//tr`, xpath is searching for all the `<tr>` occurences. If you add `[something]` after this, it is searching if this `something` exists inside the current `<tr>` in the search loop. But if you use `//something`, the doubl it means search in the whole document. `//something` is always found so for each `<tr>` the condition is respected.